# In Phase 10, can a Skip card be played in the first round of a hand?

Tags: phase-10

Can a Skip card be played before all the players have had at least one chance to play? Or can it be played at anytime?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such restriction. From the rules:

> The player ends the turn by discarding one card of choice onto the discard pile.

And

> **SKIP CARDS:** When discarded, a "Skip " card causes another player to lose their next turn. The player who discards the "Skip " card chooses the player who loses their turn. When a player draws a "Skip " card, the player may discard it immediately or save it for a later turn. A "Skip " card may never be used in making Phase 8, or any other Phase. A "Skip " card may never be picked up from the discard pile.

Comment: In fact, the _game_ can play a Skip card before _anyone_ has had a chance to play: "If the dealer starts the discard pile with a "Skip" card, the first player's turn is automatically skipped."